# MVC. Передача данных при редиректе вызывает сомнения

Tags: php, mvc

Недавно начал изучать **MVC**, и у меня возник непростой вопрос.

Допустим, имеется две страницы - главная и страница продажи акций.
Когда я осуществляю продажу акций, то меня должно перебрасывать на главную страницу (index.php), на которой должна появиться надпись "Продано!".

Я пока не нашёл способа более подходящего, чем в контроллере (sell.php) в конце кода прописать: `$_SESSION["form"] = "sold"; redirect("/");`. А на главной странице выводить текст, на основе значения данной переменной, и сразу же её удалять: `unset($_SESSION["form"])`.

Моё решение кажется мне порочным, т.к., например, если я решу сделать перенаправление не на главную страницу, то мне придётся следить за тем, чтобы удалялась переменная `$_SESSION["form"]`. В противном случае пользователь оказавшись потом на главной странице увидит сообщение "Продано!".

Я не ищу какой-нибудь костыль чуть лучше моего. Мне хотелось бы знать правильное решение данного вопроса. И мне кажется, что оно не связано ни с куками, ни с параметрами GET, которые я не желаю лишний раз видеть в адресной строке.

Comment: Делаете единую точку входа и применяете описанный вами метод. Тогда у вас будет гарантия, что на любой странице вы опустошите значение в сессии

Comment: а кто мешает делать обработку флеш-сообщений в отдельном скрипте, который и подключается во все остальные сткрипты? Но главное что я не понял - при чем здесь MVC

Comment: @ArchDemon то ли я дурак, то ли то, что вы написали попросту не будет работать. Ведь если в единой точки опустошать значение переменной ```$_SESSION["form"]```, то при редиректе на неё с sell.php, там не будет появляться необходимая надпись ("Продано!").

Comment: @Ипатьев а как этот скрипт будет понимать, с какой страницы мы пришли? С sell.php и надо показать надпись, или с любой другой, и надпись показывать не надо.

Comment: у вас какие-то странные фантазии. если пришел с другой страницы, то в сессии ничего и не будет. какая разница вообще, с какой страницы пришел человек? и с удалением непонятно что вам непонятно. разумеется, код сначала показывает сообщение, а потом удаляет. что здесь сложного?

Comment: @Ипатьев я подумаю. Но на всякий случай скажу, что у меня в контроллере главной странице вызывается функция ```render("portfolio.php", ["title" => "Портфель", "positions" => $positions]);```. Чтобы в шаблоне portfolio.php появилась какая-либо переменная, её можно только передать через функцию render. Т.е., если до вызова этой функции написать ```$text= "lalala"```, то шаблон этой переменной не увидит. При этом в самом шаблоне подключать какие-либо файлы, насколько я знаю, плохая практика.

Comment: Ну в качестве исключения шаблонизатор обычно сам ходит в хранилище флеш-сообщений

Comment: То ли вы дурак. У вас все скрипты подключаются через главный файл. В главном файле (единая точка входа), будет считываться значение и обнуляться. Считанное значение передаётся во view (mVc). Чего непонятного?

Comment: @ArchDemon единой точки входа я пока не делал, но смысл тот же. Короче, я ко всем контроллерам подключил файл **common.php**, в котором у меня есть код: `if (isset($_SESSION["form"])) { $text = $_SESSION["form"]; unset($_SESSION["form"]); }`. Это в принципе решает проблему и расширяет будущие возможности. Только я, как новичок, не знаю, насколько правильно иметь "дополнительный контроллер" в виде **common.php**.

Comment: Благодаря вашим советам, господа, я всё сделал. Спасибо.